# Flashing PCA10040 NRF52 using J-link and Segger Embedded Studio

Tags: microcontroller, flash, firmware, j-link, nrf52832

I encountered a problem while trying to flash my PCA10040 nrf52 development kit.

I am able to compile my code in Segger Embedded Studio without a problem. The chip has 512kB of flash and 24kB which should be more than enough to flash the chip.

[image]

Then I start flashing and I get this error message:

[image]

When I look at the log I see this:

[image]

If someone can help I would greatly appreciate it. I am open to provide with more information if something is missing.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware, but Nordic have their own support forum (https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/) which might provide more taylored answers if you don't get the answer you are looking for here.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try there too!